# Given $A$ and $B$ below, is the set $A \cup B$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ connected, path connected and locally connected?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set $A \cup B$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ connected, path connected and locally connected? Where
$$
A = \bigcup_n A_n,\ \ A_n = \{(x,x/n)\ |\ 0 \leq x \leq 1\}, \ \ B=\{ (x,0)\ |\ 1/2≤x≤1\}.
$$
I did a sketch and the set $B$ is basically a line segment on the  $x$ axis from 1/2 to 1 while for $A$ I got a triangle with vertices $F(0,0)$ $D(1,1)$ and $E$ somewhere above the $x$ axis [above $L(1,0)$] which would mean that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Now I assume that by definition $A\cup B$ is disconnected and since every path connected set is connected, $A\cup B$ is also not path connected. But is $A\cup B$ locally connected?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space $X = A \cup B$ is connected, but not path connected nor locally connected.

Indeed both $A$ and $B$ are path connected. Recall that given a connected subspace $Y \subset \mathbb R^2$, and a limit point $x$ of $Y$, we have that $Y \cup \{x\}$ is also connected. One can see that every point in $B$ is a limit point of $A$ and so we can conclude that $A \cup B$ is connected.

$X$ is not path connected, since there is no path between a point of $A$ and a point of $B$ (the argument for this is similar to that of the topologists sine curve). Similarly $X$ is not locally connected, and one can see this by considering a small open ball $B$ around the point $(1,0)$. This ball contains no connected open subsets, and so $X$ cannot be locally connected.

*Quick edit*: Note that it's a common early mistake to make that $A$ and $B$ being disjoint implies that $A \cup B$ is disconnected. As an easy counter example, consider $A = [0,1)$, $B = [1,2]$.